# What version of Twitter Bootstrap is Joomla 3.1.x using?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am trying to determine which version(s) of Twitter Bootstrap Joomla 3.1.x uses.

Twitter Bootstrap 3 was "recently" released and has some different parameters than the 2.x version.  [GetBootstrap webpage](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/08/19/bootstrap-3-released/)

Specifically I need to know what version of the "default" joomla 3.1 template Prostar is using.

Or, can I just look at the bootstrap.css file -- would there be any clues as to what version of bootstrap it uses.  I've looked at my copy and it is not commented so far as what version of bootstrap it uses.

Looking forward to any enlightenment here!

Answer (score 2):

As stated Joomla currently uses 2.3.2 but since there is no guarantee that this will not change in future upgrades you might consider unsetting the JUI version of Bootstrap and use your own local/static version. To stop the JUI version of Bootstrap loading use the unset command like this for each file...

```
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/jui/css/bootstrap.css']);
```

Then load your own version of bootstrap - there's a few ways you can do it but this is my preferred method...

```
        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        $doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/bootstrap.css');
```

Again, you want to do this for each file that you wish to unset or include.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 3.1 is using Bootstrap 2.3.2

To check which version, simply open either the *bootstrap.js* or *bootstrap.css* files located in:

```
root/media/jui/
```

and it will display  `* Bootstrap v2.3.2`

Hope this helps

Comment: just a small note: Joomla 3.4.8 still included Bootstrap 2.3.2

Comment: And unfortunately they use a customised version of BS2.3.2

Answer (score -1):

**Let me prefix this answer with: This was based on the assumption the question was asking how to identify the version from the output CSS shown on the website. Which you can find [here](http://joomla31.cloudaccess.net/templates/protostar/css/template.css), which you will notice doesn't retain the version or license.**

Unfortunately, joomla rip out the attribution from the CSS file referencing bootstrap so it would take quite a bit of investigating (seeing what changes had been made from 2.3.x to another version of 2.3.x) - however it is easy to be able to tell if its a 2.x.x branch or a 3.x.x branch.

Obvious way to check is just to look at the css, if it references items such as `span1, span2 ,span*` etc, it's part of the 2.x.x branch.

If however you see references to `col-md-4, col-md-5, col-md-*` then you can be sure it's of the 3.x.x branch.

Comment: What are you talking about. just look at the file in jui.

Comment: @Elin I was assuming this question was based on the outputted template.css file that is generated on for the template in production. Where you will notice there is no reference to the version. However the bootstrap.js file retains the attribution.

Comment: template.css is produced via LESS compiling.

Comment: I'd started to assume as much after some tweets with Don Gilbert and a few others. How does that work license wise, does it not need to retain the license as long as it exists in the source files?

Comment: are you distributing your files? If not you don't have to worry about providing the license to people who you distribute to.  Further it is the source files that matter not the compiled ones.